# Pass multiple variables in URL - Jinja2/Webapp2

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2

Right now my app has a link which when pressed, goes to another page and passes the variable to the request handler like so:

`<a href="/assign/{{ result.key.id() }}">Assign</a></th>`

This results in `{{ result.key.id() }}` being passed to this request handler:

```
class AssignHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self, entityID):
```

This is how I am handling the routing:

`(r'/assign/(\d+)', AssignHandler),`

By doing this I can pass a single variable into my request handler, my question is how do I adapt this so I can pass in multiple variables?

My current thinking is I need to do something like this with the link:

`<a href="/assign/{{ result.key.id() }}/{{ result.memberId }}">Assign</a>`

and then pass in two variables to the handler like so:

```
class AssignHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self, entityID, memberID):
```

But that doesn't work, so I am asking for help.

Comment: In the django framework there is a way to pass multiple variables in Jinja2 but the syntax looks different. I'm not sure if I can help as things may be different in Webapp2.

Answer (score 0):

One way to be to put all of your variables into an object and then just pass a Json for that object through, that way you would just have a single string variable being passed and it should all work